# Parse.com fetchInbackground is deprecated?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

```
_facebookResponseCount = 0;
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackgroundWithTarget:self selector:@selector(refreshCurrentUserCallbackWithResult:error:)];
```

i am trying to run the anyPic parse.com app on my Xcode but i get the error parse fetchInBackgroundWithTarget is deprecated.use WithBlock PFObject instead.I have tried correcting it but have failed to find the correct code.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock`:

Objective-C:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *fetchedUser, NSError *error) {
    //Code here
}];
```

Swift:

```
PFUser.currentUser()!.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ 
            (fetchedUser: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // Code here         
})
```